# ArgumentParser: remove capitalized names of arguments from the help message

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have a script that accepts a command line argument in the following way:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', help="accepts foo")
```

When I request `--help` for the script, it prints the following output:

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f FOO, --foo FOO     accepts foo
```

**Problem:** It prints a capitalized name of the argument: `FOO`.

**Question:** How do I remove `FOO` from the output?

I want to have the same output as for `--help`:

```
  -f, --foo             accepts foo
```

Comment: `-f, --foo` would mean that this option _doesn't_ accept any arguments, which isn't the case.

Comment: @ForceBru thanks! Could you post this as an answer. It wasn't obvious from the documentation.

Comment: Well, that's not really an answer, I just wanted to say that this _notation_ means that `--foo` _does not _ "accept foo" or that the argument is optional, so if you were to use it in your program, the users will be confused

Answer (score 0):

`parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo',action=True, defalut=False, help="accepts foo")`
 in options will make `--foo` an arg, your soulotion defines a kwarg and `FOO` indicates that a key value is required after argument